# How configure a django project in apache2 step by step? (Ubuntu)

Tags: django, python-2.7, apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I need to configure my project in django in apache2 using ubuntu. These are the files that I have configured and how I have done it.

My django project is /var/www/auxiliar_api directory.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/auxiliar_api.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIDaemonProcess auxiliar_api.com python-home=/usr/bin/python3.5 python-path=/$
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/wwww/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api/wsgi.py
ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
ServerName auxiliar_api.com
ServerAlias www.auxiliar_api.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api
Alias /static/ /var/www/auxiliar_api/static/
<Directory /var/www/auxiliar_api/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api/wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "auxiliar_api.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I try to access localhost this is the error that I get in the browser

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I need to know what other files I should configure and how? Also if I need to modify some of the configurations that I have made and what do I show them?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: You have ``/var/wwww/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api/wsgi.py``. Is that actually what you have or a typo? Should it be ``/var/www/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api/wsgi.py``? That is, ``www`` not ``wwww``.

Comment: Unrelated, but ``python-home=/usr/bin/python3.5`` is wrong also. That is not meant to be set to a binary, but a directory. It is only needed if using a virtual environment or Python is in a non standard location. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: You should also not set ``DocumentRoot`` to be ``/var/www/auxiliar_api/auxiliar_api``. It is not needed and if you comment out ``WSGIScriptAlias`` people can then download your source code.

Comment: Finally, what is ``python-path`` actually set to. Looks like it should be ``/var/www/auxiliar_api`` but you may have just truncated the line.

Answer (score -1):

You have to grant the permissions by using
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/auxiliar_api/
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

Comment: You should never recommend anyone set permissions of 777 on directories and files as that is making their system more vulnerable.